# Proving that there are $n-1$ roots in $a_1x^{b_1}+a_2x^{b_2}+...+a_nx^{b_n}=0 $ on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus

> We know that:
>
> $a_1,...,a_n\in \mathbb R , \forall a_i\neq0 \\
> b_1,...,b_n\in \mathbb R : b_j\neq b_k : \forall j\neq k$
>
> Prove that there are $n-1$ roots in $(0,\infty)$:
>
> $$a_1x^{b_1}+a_2x^{b_2}+...+a_nx^{b_n}=0  $$

Using induction, for n=1 it's obvious that there are 0 roots.

Suppose the statement is true for n-2 and prove for n-1:

From here on I'm not sure how to continue, I noticed that $x^{b_1}(a_1 + \ldots + a_n x^{b_n - b_1})=0$ but at what point can it come into the induction process ? Also, how does the IVT is applied here ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of 623757...

Comment: The hint given by Israel, together with what the OP mentions there, is enough, @GinKin

Comment: If you knew the other post, why not even mention it in your question?

Comment: If the other post did not help you, it seems crucial to indicate to potential answerers the reason why, if only to avoid that they produce a similar answer which would also leave you unsatisfied, as the old one did. For this reason, and since your question is now closed, it seems obvious that omitting this context from your question had the opposite effect to the one you thought.

Comment: Then everything is allright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

So now just work with $\;a_1 +a_2x^{b_2-b_1}+\ldots+a_nx^{b_n-b_1}\;$,  differentiate and get **less** than $\;n\;$ summands. Now use what the other question mentions about the relation between the zeros of the derivative of a function and those of the function itself.

Comment: Why we can derive here ? Also, I don't get at what point of the induction process the $x^{b_1}$ can be taken out.

Comment: Why wouldn't we be able to derive here, @GinKin ? We have here an irrational function well defined, and the induction goes on the number of non-zero coefficients...

Comment: If we can derive once, what's stopping us from doing the same process of taking out an $x^{b_i}$ and deriving n times ? I probably miss something but it feels like cheating...

Comment: You derive **once** and *then use* the inductive hypothesis on  the derivative! Then you use the lemma mentioned by Timbuc in the old post...

Comment: That was my question, what is the inductive hypothesis here ? And the lemma, you mean this: "I can prove that if $\;f'(x)=0\;$ has $\;n-1\;$ different zeros, then $\;f(x)\;$ has at most $\;n\;$ different zeros" I don't know where he brought this from, we haven't been shown this and I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Can you answer my above comment or give any more hints please ?

Comment: For that claim use the MVT, @GinKin : for any two consecutive roots of $\;f\;$ there is a root in between of $\;f'\;$ . For the induction part: $$\left(a_1+a_2x^{b_2-b_1}+\ldots+a_nx^{b_n-b_1}\right)'=a_2(b_2-b_1)x^{b_2-b_1-1}+\ldots+a_n(b_n-b_1)x^{b_n-b_1-1}$$ By the Ind. Hyp. the last function has at most $\;n-2\;$ different zero, and thus our function has at most $\;n-1\;$ different zeros

Comment: Thanks. I finaly got it. The lemma, between each $0$ of $f$ there's an extramum where $f'$ is a $0$. So $n$ and $n-1$, it's like our fingers and the gaps between them (there must be a name for this principle).